# Calculating area of different classes in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to classify the India into forest, agriculture and urban areas using Google Earth Engine, but after classification I am trying to calculate areas of classes like this:

```
var im=l8.filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31');
var cloudless =im.map(function(image) {
  var cloudy = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore(image).select('cloud');
  var mask = cloudy.lte(20)
  return image.updateMask(mask);
});
var cld=cloudless.median();
var cloud=cld.clipToCollection(ind);
```

do the classification:

```
var classNames=urban.merge(forest).merge(agriculture).merge(water);
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'];
var training = cloud.select(bands).sampleRegions({
 collection: classNames
properties: ['landcover'],
scale: 30
});
var classifier = ee.Classifier.randomForest().train({
 features: training,
 classProperty: 'landcover',
 inputProperties: bands
});
var classified = cloud.select(bands).classify(classifier);
Map.addLayer(classified,{min: 0, max: 3, palette: ['red', 'green', 'yellow','blue']},'classification');
```

Calculate the area of different classes

```
var names = ['urb','for','agri','watr']
var count = classified.eq([0,1,2,3]).rename(names);
var total = count.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());
var area = total.reduceRegion({
 reducer:ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry:ind,
  scale:30,
 maxPixels: 1e9,
 bestEffort:true
});
var area_pxa = ee.Number(area).divide(1e6)
print ('Area in (km²):', area_pxa)
```

When I am running this, it is taking a lot of time and showing error:

> computation timed out.

How to overcome this error?

Here is the link to my code:https://code.earthengine.google.com/08783af235d2672177f2af9f1d81e714

Answer (score 1):

The computation is too large (scale, extent, complexity, etc) to complete in the roughly 5 minutes that a request is allowed when working interactively in the Code Editor.

You could try to export your classification as an asset, before calculating the areas. Include something like this in your script:

```
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: classified,
  description: 'my_classification',
  scale: 30,
  pyramidingPolicy: {'.default': 'mode'}
})
```

Go to the "Tasks" section on the right hand side, and select 'Run'. Look at the docs for more details on how to do the export (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting). Once your task completes, you can import your classification and do further processing on it.

```
var classified = ee.Image('users/yourUserName/my_classification')
```

Comment: @Daniel, Hi. Could you explain how to implement your answer, so that a user interested in applying it can reproduce it?

Comment: Hi,Daniel thanks for the reply.I am very new to Google Earth Engine,can you please explain little more how to implement this .

Comment: I updated my answer with an example on how to export the classification.

Comment: Also, please see the [Use-Export](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/debugging#use-export) section of the Developer Guide's Debugging page. Earth Engine tries to give you results in near-real-time in the browser, but for some operations, this is not possible and results in either timeout or computation too large messages. The browser is good for quickly checking a workflow. For instance, if you are trying to classify all of India, try setting the scale at `1000` or greater, just to see that the process worked. Then, do as Daniel suggests and export the result at `30` meters.

Comment: when i am exporting the image classified,I am getting error:Request payload size exceeds the limit: 4194304 bytes.How to overcome this?