# Min NDVI estimation from NDVI time series

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

I'm trying to estimate max min NDVI values from the NDVI datasets that came from Landsat images 4-5-7-8. For the max NDVI I used the "qualityMosaic" and it seems that it works okay, but for the min NDVI value I get an error message

> MIN NDVI: Layer error: Computation timed out

I've attached the GEE code.

```
// Function to cloud mask Landsat 8.
var maskL8SR = function(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(3).int();
  var cloudsBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(5).int();
  // Get the QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0).and(
            qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image
      // Scale the data to reflectance and temperature.
      .select(['B4', 'B5'], ['RED', 'NIR']).multiply(0.0001)
      .addBands(image.select(['B11'], ['Thermal']).multiply(0.1))
      .updateMask(mask);
};

// Function to cloud mask Landsats 5-7
var maskL57SR = function(image) {
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Second bit must be zero, meaning none to low cloud confidence.
  var mask1 = qa.bitwiseAnd(ee.Number(2).pow(7).int()).eq(0).and(
      qa.bitwiseAnd(ee.Number(2).pow(3).int()).lte(0)); // cloud shadow
  // This gets rid of irritating fixed-pattern noise at the edge of the images.
  var mask2 = image.select('B.*').gt(0).reduce('min');
  return image
      .select(['B3', 'B4'], ['RED', 'NIR']).multiply(0.0001)
      .addBands(image.select(['B6'], ['Thermal']).multiply(0.1))
      .updateMask(mask1.and(mask2));
};

// find all data and filter them by date
var lst5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
    .filterDate('1984-10-01', '2011-10-01')
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .map(maskL57SR)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)});

var lst7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate('2011-10-01', '2013-04-07')
  .filterBounds(roi)
  .map(maskL57SR)
  .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)});

 var lst8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
     .filterDate('2013-04-07', '2018-05-01')
    .filterBounds(roi)
  .map(maskL8SR)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(roi)});


// Combine all landsat data, 1985 through 2015
var L4578 = ee.ImageCollection(lst5.merge(lst8));
L4578 = L4578.merge(lst7);


// create function to add NDVI using NIR (B5) and the red band (B4)
var getNDVI = function(img1){
  return img1.addBands(img1.normalizedDifference(['NIR','RED']).rename('NDVI'));
};

// map over image collection
var l8ndvi = L4578.map(getNDVI).select('NDVI');




///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// for each pixel, select the "best" set of bands from available images
// based on the maximum NDVI/greenness
var composite = l8ndvi.qualityMosaic('NDVI').clip(roi);

print (composite);

//set visualization parameters for Maximum NDVI            

var ndviParams = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(composite.select('NDVI'), ndviParams, 'Maximun NDVI');


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//For each pixel, select the "worst" set of bands from available images
//based on minimum NDVI
// reduce the image collection to one image by taking MIN of the rasters
var reducemin_NDVI = l8ndvi.reduce(ee.Reducer.min());


// get min NDVI values by ROI polygon

var NDVImin = reducemin_NDVI.reduceRegions({
  collection: roi,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  scale: 30 // the resolution of the dataset

});

//set visualization parameters for MIN NDVI            

var ndviParams = {min: 0, max: 1, palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(NDVImin, ndviParams, 'MIN NDVI');
```

Comment: This Q & A on computation timeout might be helpful:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/346301/68792

Comment: maybe it needs to remove the null values for estimating the min NDVI image from all NDVI time series. How could I do that?